# Initialize CChar or UInt8 from string literals with zero run-time overhead (Swift)

Tags: swift

How can I initialize `CChar` or `UInt8` with string literals in Swift?

```
extension UInt8 : ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible {
    public static func convertFromExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral(value: String) -> UInt8 {
        let num = value.unicodeScalars[value.unicodeScalars.startIndex]
        return UInt8(num.value)
    }
}

let a: UInt8 = "A"

println(a)
```

This is my try, but I guess it is executed in run-time. How can I do that with zero run-time overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can't. That's what swift uses for any other data type initializable with a literal. For instance, the `String` type implements:

```
extension String : ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible {
    static func convertFromExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral(value: String) -> String
}
```

and that enables `String` variables to be initialized with string literals

So, the way you are doing is the right way.